# Excel Formula to Compare and Import Certain Information between Sheets

Tags: excel-formula

I am working on a new spreadsheet that is an update to a spreadsheet from last year. I'm trying to fill in blank columns for this year's data by importing them from the other sheet. However, the order and information has changed from last year and I'm looking for a way to fill the columns in the correct row by comparing only the information that corresponds to the same information from last year.

I have these columns in both sheets:

2014 Rank - 2013 Rank - Address - City - Zip Code

I need to create a formula that will compare the Address, City, and Zip Codes from both sheets and then insert the 2014 and 2013 Ranks into this year's data in the corresponding rows.

The issue is that the ranking from this year has completely changed the order of the rankings from last year so the formula needs to know to search the entire sheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd go on a limb here and say, have you tried `=vlookup()`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how that vlookup formula is supposed to look inside the parentheses... If the 2014 Rank is in A1, 2013 Rank in A2, Address A3, City A4 and Zip A5 how would it be entered? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can create another column in each sheet, concatening the Address, City and Zip with `=CONCAT(A1,CONCAT(A2,A3))` and then use `=VLOOKUP()` to search on this new column.

More info on VLOOKUP (Theres working examples on how to retrieve more than one column and several other stuff):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: I understand concatenating the address columns but I still don't understand how to set up the VLOOKUP formula to take the values from the other 2 columns and put them in the new sheet.. Or how to make it reference the sheet with the info I need.

Comment: Kind of random Bruno but is there any way I could "hire" you to help me out? I need it done pretty quickly and I have no where near enough knowledge on this subject to get it done myself apparently. I don't think it would take very long for someone who knows what they're doing. Unfortunately that is not me...